# Como debugar em C#?

Tags: c#, debug

Como debugar em C# tomando como referência a forma simples do PHP que geralmente se usa `var_dump` ou `print_r`?

Tenho um objeto em C# mas não sei como saber o que há na estrutura dele.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As 3 primeiras opções mostradas aqui é necessário adicionar um `break point` no seu código para visualizar a estrutura do `objeto`:

> **1.** Após a `IDE` pausar o código no `Break Point`, clique na aba
>   `Immediate Windows`, digite `?` e o `objeto/variável`, etc e tecle
>   <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **2.** Clique na aba `Local` e navegue pelos `objetos/variáveis,etc`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **3**. `Mouse Over` sobre o objeto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **4**. A aba `Output` mostra, dentre outras informações, o resultado do comando `WriteLine`, ex: `Debug.WriteLine(objeto.propriedade);`, neste caso não é necessário `Break Point`

[Guia do usuário do Visual Studio IDE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn762121.aspx)